# Springboot build not working because of test configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I have started a spring boot project using start.spring.io.
But I am getting this error- 
I have read various articles on the internet about this issue and they all say about putting my tests in the same package as my Main class.
But I already have the same.
Could you point out what is wrong with my configuration?
[image]

Comment: Is your `DatabaseApplication` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty clear: You are missing a configuration for your spring context. What you need to do is to add the configuration classes for your context like so:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfiguration.class })
```

whereas your TestConfiguration class must be annotated with

```
@Configuration
```

and/or

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

There you can add configurations to your liking. You can of course also use your DatabaseApplication class as Configuration although Im wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found.

Make Sure your DatabaseApplication class is annotated with @SpringBootApplication .